# How can we tell the difference between matter and antimatter by observation in space?

Tags: observational-astronomy, antimatter

I just was wondering and searching on the internet with little luck in the topic. On Antimatter Wiki they tell the observable universe is built up by matter. I read antimatter can be detected in cosmic rays in very small quantity. But let's go in theories and our practical knowledge, my question is:

How could we detect if a set of objects (like an entire galaxy) is completely built up by antimatter? Since matter and antimatter look like "mirror image" on current, could they form a similar object which is indistinguishable from "our" matter objects? I mean, would spectrum analysis for example show that it is not matter, but built up by antimatter?

Linked question: Are we sure about that what we see in universe is matter?

Comment: I think the answer is we can't.   An entire galaxy made up of anti-matter would look exactly like a galaxy made up of matter.  (as far as I know).   But maybe some experts should answer this with more certainty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Tl;DR

- Detection via **polarized light** - Antimatter interaction with polarized light could be detected by vector rotation;
- We're ***mostly* sure**, because absence of gamma rays and characteristic Faraday polarization indicates absence of observable antimatter in meaningful amounts.

### Long answer

I do believe @userLTK to be correct on his comment.

To my limited knowledge, the absence of gamma-ray bursts that characterizes matter-antimatter interactions hints of baryonic matter prevalence throughout the visible universe; an anti-galaxy near a baryonic galaxy would show a healthy amount of gamma rays originating from boundary particle collisions.

[image]

This effect would be observable between structures of any scale - e.g. star/anti-star, galaxy/anti-galaxy or supercluster/anti-supercluster.

["Light from the Depths of Time"](https://books.google.com/books?id=H3fpCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), by Rudolph Kippenhahn, mentions that

> [...] Even when, like a star, it is radiation, its spectrum remains
>   exactly the same, quite independent of whether atoms or anti-atoms are
>   responsible for the light.

So the light originating from anti-galaxies would look the same as ordinary galaxies. But what about gravity?

A quote from ["Isodual Theory of Antimatter: with applications to Antigravity, Grand Unification and Cosmology"](https://books.google.com/books?id=T43ZoeIan64C&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=light%20originating%20from%20anti-matter&source=bl&ots=u6_o3ZWqEv&sig=TzYMlXCz2SzPKCmsXspvOWQ6MW4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lsldVfnJI4GqNvCkgagN&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=light%20originating%20from%20anti-matter&f=false) may help us further:

> [...] However, the photons is invariant under charge conjugation and
>   travel at the maximal causal speed in vacuum, *c*. Therefore, the
>   photon could well result to be a superposition of positive and
>   negative energies, perhaps as a condition to travel at the speed *c*,
>   in which case the photon would be an isoselfdual state, thus
>   experiencing attraction in both fields of matter and antimatter.

Meaning that antimatter would also cause gravitational effects, such as lensing.

That would make remote detection of anti-matter quite hard - it would emit and bend light in exactly the same fashion as common matter.

Faraday polarization rotation could give us some hope:

> Polarized light, e.g., from non-thermal synchrotron sources, that
>   passes through gas with a non-zero magnetic field will have its
>   polarization vector rotated by the process of Faraday rotation. [...]
>   Note that regions dominated by antimatter (positrons) cause a rotation
>   **opposite** to that caused by regions dominated by matter (electrons).

([SLAC Summer Institute on Particle Physics (SSI04), Aug. 2-13, 2004](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C040802/papers/L017.PDF))

But the same source mentions that

> The effect has been measured many times and the amount of rotation,
>   usually expressed in terms of the so-called “rotation measure” is
>   given by the line-of-sight integral [...] The fact that we observe an
>   effect at all means that on average, we can’t have equal amounts of
>   antimatter and matter along our various lines of sight.

So it seems that the visible universe is missing some antimatter after all.